# Is there any option in tortoise SVN to delete a revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have accidently deleted some file and commited. 
So  I need to delete that revision. 
Otherwise whenever i update revision my files are deleting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you cannot delete a revision in svn. You can only commit new revision restoring previous changes.

You need to merge old revision (where the file persists) into working copy and then commit it.

Comment: +1 Because the user already committed the change to the repository.  Therefore, doing a revert with the client (even Tortoise) will not make that file reappear.  This the is the more appropriate answer for the question asked.

Comment: +1 Better than my solution now that we know what the actual question is.

Answer (score 3):

You can revert your working copy to a particular revision and then commit that. Remember that TortoiseSVN is nothing but a client. You can't do anything via the client that you can't do via a command line.

What's your scenario?

Comment: Ya i reverted back to a previous revision but the problem is even if i revert it and commit.. when I update the files are again deleted

Answer (score 1):

I just voted for @babak's solution but if it's *really* important for you and you have access to the repository, you could remove the specific revision using svnadmin dump and dumpfilter.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you cannot delete a revision but there is a workaround which should achieve the same goal. You can commit a new revision which rewrites the previous one. There is an option in tortoise svn how to automatize this process. Its called reverse merging. It means you merge the branch with itself. I have successfully used this function. Following screenshots should guide you through this task.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Good advice: be aware that various 3rd party tools for 3-way merging are sometimes not reliable. They can get you code that can be compiled but fails at runtime. I prefer using default TortoiseMerge application for merging as you can see from following setting.

[image]